# How to convert to int AngularJS element in C# ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want use AngularJS output for calculate DiscountPercent  in ASP.Net Razor.
when i use `@int.pars()` or `@Convert.ToInt32` for calculate, Error displays.
I need a code similar to this

```
 <td ng-repeat="ro in room.Roms">
       (@Convert.ToInt32({{ro.RRPrice}})* @Convert.ToInt32({{ ro.DiscountPercent}}))/ 100 ;
 </td>
```

how to solve this problem?

Comment: You cannot use frontend variables (angular) in backend (Razor) code. The razor is already parsed server-side, while the angular code is evaluated in the browser

Comment: Why don't you do this using Angular ?

Comment: i should use javascript for calculate?

Comment: How do I use angular for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find solution

```
 {{ro.RRPrice * ro.DiscountPercent/100 }}
```

it ok.
thank you